# Mostrar um EditText ao clicar no FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout

Vejam se pode me ajudar estou começando a trabalhar com FloatingButton gostaria de quando o usuário clicar no botão aparece um EditText para digitação e um botão ao final para apagar o texto, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei esse `FrameLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/calc_txt_Prise"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/barDarkColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:hint="@string/app_name"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calc_clear_txt_Prise"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_close" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Mas agora como poderia chamar para exibir?

Answer (score 0):

```
 FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewbyId(frame_layout);

 FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab)
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
                 frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Desse jeito deve funcionar, só que eu acho melhor você usar um `LinearLayout` horizontal pois tem dois filhos diretos, e o `FrameLayout`(se não me engano) é utilizado quando tem apenas um

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer de dois jeitos:

- Inflar esse FrameLayout/Inflar e usar na view de um AlertDialog
- Colocar o edt e o botão na mesmo layout que o floatingbutton e trabalhar com a visibilidade

  setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
  setVisibility(View.GONE)